# SQL query to update all subpages of a specific uid in TYPO3

Tags: mysql, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-8.x

I'm looking to find an SQL query to update my TYPO3 table (pages) to add a specific fe_group for all pages under a specific uid in the page tree.

Example: `UPDATE pages SET fe_group = 16 WHERE pid = 84;`

This will add my fe_group to all pages under my specific uid in the page tree but only for the first level under. I need to reach the infinite levels.

TYPO3 v6.2 and above
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply usergroup access rights to all subpages of a page, there is a built in function the page properties already: `Extend to Subpages`.
This works in all TYPO3 versions you mentioned:

[image]

[image]

If you really want to do it with an SQL query, you need to create a small PHP script to recursively change the access rights.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the answer. I do need an SQL query. It's for an external .sql file which I run every 24 hours by a cron. I have an Intranet exported to an Extranet every 24 hours. I need to apply those fe_group only to the Extranet when exported.

Comment: It should be easier to run the SQL update command just for the specifc uid and set `fe_group` and `extendToSubpages`. Than all child pages are covered as well.

Comment: You are totally right! I will do it this way. Thank you so much Peter for your time!. Hugo.